# rails admin, create a button that runs custom code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

in my rails app I need to generate a bunch of buttons/links linked to several models to enable users to run some maintenance tasks (coded in the Backend).

I found the concept of actions in rails admin here: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Actions, but I'm not quite clear how to use it, any ideas?

I thought I could add the buttons to the edit action for a model, but no ideas how to.

Comment: not really, I already seen that question, and had already checked their wiki, that link in the answer is the one I posted

Answer (score 0):

Sooo, rails uses an MVC paradigm. It sounds like you have the View and Model components under control, but you are missing your Controller logic. The Controller, is a place that handles any View logic using Model methods... ideally.

So, if you already have an existing controller that you are trying to add "Controller Actions" to... you need to define your custom method actions you want to create in your `config/routes.rb` file.

This will look like the following:

1. Create a route for your new controller action.
2. Add new controller action definition to your Controller.
3. Call controller action in your view's button link_to tag helper
4. Handle your custom logic in your new controller action using model methods

This is the cyclical MVC nature of Rails. M (Model), V (View), C (Controller).